# Make a href tag so user can download picture to their photo folder

Tags: cordova

I want to create an href tag inside my phonegap app so that user can click on it and have the file downloaded to their photos folder.
Can it be done through html mark up alone? if not, what else do I need?

Answer (score 1):

You will need Javascript too, besides HTML and CSS. There is a plugin for PhoneGap you might want to check out: [FileTransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/dev/doc/index.md) or you can use my plugin: [Downloader](https://gist.github.com/teusinkorg/6572976).